# Is is possible to share elements or parts of a page on social media sites?

Tags: twitter, share, facebook-social-plugins

I'm hoping this is a pretty simple question to answer. I have a page with 6 recipes on it. I'm being asked to include share buttons for each recipe and they want the shares on FB or Twitter to be formatted to use a specific image and text for each recipe. This is something we would normally handle via Open Graph metatags and the like, but that only works at the page-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a separate URL/page for each Like/Share. But you can redirect to the main page, or just use a GET parameter. For example, each Like/Share Button can use the following URL: `http://www.yourdomain.com/yourrecipepage.php?recipeid=x`

The "x" being dynamic, of course. Now you can check the recipeid parameter and use different OG tags. the rest of the page will be the same. I hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. We can tag the specific recipe in the URL (via the id). But then you say we can check the ID and use different OG tags. How do we manage/create different OG tags for each recipe? (BTW - we're trying to share, not get likes. I'm not entirely sure what the differences in the process would be)

Comment: as i said, that would be possible with PHP, for example. and it does not matter if you want to share or like, the same OG tags will be used.

Comment: PHP would allow me to set the Open Graph tags when the page is parsed on the server, but I can still only have one set of OG tags, correct? My shares would still be using the same OG data, wouldn't it?

Comment: no, you just need to use different links (=different get parameters) for every share plugin.

Comment: I see where my confusion is coming from. You're talking about the links back to the site and how to get those to behave, and this is a good solution. My concern is the information that actually gets shared on the service (FB, Twitter, etc) and the image and text used there. This is what I'm trying to individualize or isolate within the page. If I want to share a recipe for a Manhattan, I'd like only that art and summary to be shared, not the generic page info.

Comment: exactly, that's why you can use the same page for sharing, but with a different get parameter. different get parameter means different og tags with php.

Comment: Can I use different return urls on facebook after share, for example I have the following links to share http://www.yourdomain.com/yourrecipepage.php?recipeid=120, http://www.yourdomain.com/yourrecipepage.php?recipeid=121 etc..... But After sharing in facebook, Is it possible for me to redirect back to another link say http://www.yourdomain.com/landing.php  for all shared links ?

Comment: well, you could do a javascript redirection, so facebook will ignore it